# Ultimaker Cura 4.8 / How to specify bed (Print) Area?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, heated-bed

Repetier-host has a setting to specify the "print area". That's roughly the size of the bed.

Note that the printer head can go out of those bounds, in my case my bed is very undersized compared to the printer frame, but this would also be an issue if you had clips or some obstacles in the bed.

Is there a similar setting in Cura where I can specify the "print area"/"bed size"/"margins" to be different from the printer width/depth?

Thanks.

**Repetier host settings:**

[image: Repetier-host]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The print area settings would be in the Preferences > Printers. Select the particular printer on the left side pane, then click the "Machine Settings" button.

[image]

You will need to set a printing offset [(`M206`)](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M206.html) in Marlin: via **Start G-code** in Cura, or any other suitable way (LCD configuration, configuration files, etc.).

Comment: Do you refer to the x(width), y(depth) settings in that image? they set where the printer can move to, but not where the *bed* is within that coordinate system. If you had a bed of 100mm x 100mm in your same frame... how do you define that there?

Comment: I see what you are asking now. I am new to 3D printing, so I would assume that the printer firmware would center the print bed within the frame of the printer. Maybe someone with more experience can shed some more light.

Comment: The build area has three dimensions (assuming we all agree to remain with a cuboid, like all slicers do). Then that's all Cura has to know. @rufo is taking advantage of "host" functionality, which (most simply) can be task of firmware like Marlin. So @argaza your answer lacks only one information: setting an printing offset ([`M206`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M206.html)) in Marlin: via **Start G-code** in Cura, or any other suitable way (LCD configuration, configuration files, etc.).

Comment: @octopus8 I have edited to add your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is the "official" solution for this, but I was able to define the "disallowed areas" in a custom printer definition.

I created a json file under C:\Program Files\Ultimaker Cura 4.8.0\resources\definitions for the printer, and added the machine_disallowed_areas section to "overrides".

```
    "machine_disallowed_areas": {
    "default_value": [ 
        [ [ -97.5, 90],[97.5,90] , [97.5,80] ,[-97.5,80] ] ,            
        [ [ -97.5, -57],[97.5,-57] , [97.5,-90] ,[-97.5,-90] ] ,
        [ [ -97.5, -90], [-49.5, -90], [-49.5,90 ] ,[-97.5, 90] ],
        [ [ 64.5, 90],  [64.5, -90], [97.5, -90], [97.5,90 ] ]
        ]
        }
```

Comment: Very interesting. Sound a bit exaggerated to reach the simple goal. If I wanted just a rectangular bed and a space above it, I would go for X,Y,Z dimensions plus home offset. The fewer numbers, the fewer places to make error.